# Click on the button to run the php function (without refreshing the page)

Tags: php, ajax, function, button, refresh

I want to make `a` and `b` buttons to execute a function without refreshing the page.

The problem is that when I call this function in `index.php` or another page, the function works as soon as the page is opened. but the page I want to do should have a button and the function should work when I click the button.

How can I do this?

```
function insta_login() {

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    \InstagramAPI\Instagram::$allowDangerousWebUsageAtMyOwnRisk = true;

    $username = 'xxxxx';
    $password = 'xxxxx';

    $ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram();

    try {
        $ig->login($username, $password);
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server which means your HTML form (client) needs to send a request to the server. Now, if you want to do this without a browser refresh, look into a technique called AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is the hypertext preprocessor, that means it will process the file, execute PHP scripts and send processed response to the client. So the plain PHP code that is not part of any function/class etc. will be always executed even before the page loads. The best option would be to declare the PHP function in a separate file. Then assign a click handler to your button and make it send Ajax request to the PHP. If you are using JQuery, it can be done easily with [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript `setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);` function.
or you can use this function `document.readyState === 'complete'` to check if page is loaded then perfom the action.
Wrap it like this

```
if(document.readyState === 'complete') {  //Your code here.... }
```

Comment: How does this solve "_should have a button and the function should work when I click the button_"?

Comment: As per my understanding that when index.php file opened the page should display two buttons.
and when you click then the function runs.
for that on click function send the ajax request and send the request to that function which you want to execute, you can also add settimeout to delay the result.

Comment: Looks like OP doesn't even have those buttons (at least he didn't post the relevant code for them) and you wouldn't need Javascript to simply display two buttons on a page